# Strange behaviour of ExternalProject_Add with a command containing a space

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clang, external-project

I need to compile boost libraries with `ExternalProject_Add`, and the build command needs
c++11 flags on MacOS platform with Clang.

The command should look like this:

```
./bin/b2 debug release cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags=-stdlib=libc++
```

But I have a problem with the quotes and space.

```
set(BOOST_CXX_FLAGS cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
set(BOOST_TOOL_SET toolset=clang ${BOOST_CXX_FLAGS}
linkflags=-stdlib=libc++)
ExternalProject_Add(boost
  ....
  BUILD_COMMAND ./bin/b2 debug release
    ${BOOST_TOOL_SET} 
  ....
)
```

The `${BOOST_TOOL_SET}` value is a list, and `cxxflags="-std=c++11
-stdlib=libc++"` is one item in it.  The generated command line becomes strange:

```
./bin/b2 debug release "cxxflags=\"-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++\""
linkflags=-stdlib=libc++
```

It seems the flag is translated by CMake when it detected the space inside the argument and wrapped it with quote marks, but it's not what I want.

I searched on the Internet, but haven't found any help.  Is there any tip about this issue?

Comment: Are you sure your desired syntax is actually correct? BTW, on any Unix shell, it is actually equivalent to what CMake produces.

Comment: I have tried the following command line on macos, and boost building is success:
    ./bin/b2 debug release cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++" linkflags=-stdlib=libc++

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
set(BOOST_CXX_FLAGS "cxxflags=-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++")
```

This should produce

```
./bin/b2 debug release "cxxflags=-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"
```

Under normal shell parsing rules, this is equivalent to what works for you:

```
./bin/b2 debug release cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question exactly, as in I can't see a way to get your requested command line to the b2 exe with the `cxxflags="-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++"` portion correctly formatted.

However, I believe you can accomplish the desired effect by calling `cxxflags=` twice.  Each argument is appended to the compiler flags eventually invoked by b2.

So you should be able to do:

```
set(BOOST_CXX_FLAGS cxxflags=-std=c++11 cxxflags=-stdlib=libc++)
```

and the eventual command invoked by b2 will be something like

```
"clang++" ... -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ ...
```

To verify this, you can add `-d+2` to your command:

```
BUILD_COMMAND ./bin/b2 debug release ${BOOST_TOOL_SET} -d+2
```

This causes the full commands to be written to the boost-build-out.log file in your boost-stamp directory.